# Identify the tip polarity on this AC adapter without plugging it in

Tags: voltage, transformer, ac-dc

I have a 230V AC-DC adapter/transformer from Europe that I am trying to replace with a 120V version. I am trying to determine the tip polarity of the DC output. I cannot simply plug it in and use a multi-meter to measure the polarity because I do not have access to a 230V/50Hz source. I have several questions:

1. Can I plug it in to 120V anyway and just look at the polarity, even if perhaps the output voltage will be wrong?
2. The only symbols on the adapter are shown below. Do any of the symbols indicate tip polarity? If so, what does it indicate?

The symbol that I have highlighted with an orange arrow looks promising, but I have been unable to find something similar on the internet. The unknown symbol is an oval with a '+' sign over the letter 'S'.

3. Perhaps the following is true? If not, perhaps I can just assume positive tip polarity if there is no symbol at all?

[image: equation]

[image: adapter image]

Comment: 1) I don't recommend plugging it in due to voltage and frequency difference. However it looks like a simple transformer, so which brings us to 2) It has no polarity as it looks like AC output transformer. So it does not have DC output. Do you have a multimeter to verify that?

Comment: Well the label suggests it's an AC adaptor, not a DC one at all. It says 240V AC input, 24V AC output

Comment: The +S symbol is a mark for Swiss electrical approval, not used after year 2002.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *I have a 230V AC-DC adapter/transformer from Europe that I am trying
> to replace with a 120V version.*

No it isn't DC out it's AC out - hence the little squiggle symbol: "~" after where it says 24V i.e. 24V~.

> *I am trying to determine the tip polarity of the DC output.*

The important things I've highlighted in red below: -

[image]

In summary, the output is AC and not DC - so you can plug it into your AC supply and determine this - operating below 230 volts won't hurt it. But if there's any doubt, be prepared with an oven glove handy and a metal box to pull it from its supply quickly should the marking I read be incorrect.

One further point and it may or may not be important - if you are trying to replace an AC adapter for something, the "something" may indeed require 50 Hz for some timing requirements and, if you are running at 60 Hz, you may get unusual results.

Comment: Excellent! I just assumed it was AC-DC but now you've made it obvious that its AC-AC. With AC-AC polarity doesn't make sense, which is why it doesn't list the polarity. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The "~" is a symbol for approximate, not AC.  The input is clearly AC as indicated by the 50Hz rating.  Plugging it in to 120V for testing would just give you half of the rated output.  The frequency difference won't be a problem short term for testing.  Use a VOM or DVM to determine whether the output is AC or DC.  As there is no polarity indicated for the output, it would be safe to assume it is AC, so polarity is not a concern.  But you know what they say about ASSume.  So, it looks like you simply have to find a 120V version with the right size (inner & outer diameter) output connector, which makes the whole polarity/testing issue moot.

Comment: Incorrect. In mathematics yes, this symbol means "approximate". However in electrical markings this symbol "~" means alternating current, or AC, as per the international symbols standard IEC 60417 (Symbol #5032).